# Does SQL Server "NOT Allow" multiple roots?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, hierarchyid

I am very new to HierarchyId world and trying to implement HierarchyId() into my SQLServer design and I was under impression that SQL Server allows only one Root node per Column per table and if I  try to something like following if a table already has a Root node then it should error out or throw some warning:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TeamHierarchy
                ( TeamNode, TeamId, TeamNodeName )
        VALUES  ( HierarchyId::GetRoot(), -- TeamNode - hierarchyid
                  1, -- TeamId - int
                  'TeamContainer'  -- TeamNodeName - varchar(50)
                  )
```

My assumption was based on some of the threads that I read :

[SQL 2008 HierarchyID with Multiple Root Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352778/sql-2008-hierarchyid-with-multiple-root-nodes)

However, it seems like SQL server does not have any problem in having multiple roots because the insert query above works perfectly fine without any errors/warning. Has anything changed since SQL server 2008 since I am using SQL Server 2012? Or there was any misunderstanding on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other non-primary key column, you can have multiple values in a column if the value is not constrained.  HierarchyID is no exception.  You can have multiple roots for your use case if the HierarchyID is not a primary key.  However if you want to constrain the Node, you need to make the HierarchyID a Primary Key, then you can only have 1 root, with many nodes under the root.

Microsoft discusses how to enforce uniqueness here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb677212(v=SQL.105).aspx